# how to make Ant Properties File for all build.xml files of project

Tags: ant, build

I want to save global settings for all build.xml files for all projects

In my project each project have its own build.xml file and 
one global build.xml to call all files

files directory path is changing while project move another place.

so I want to make one file which contains all path settings

please add some good example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing ant path-like structures from a build file in another directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175720/importing-ant-path-like-structures-from-a-build-file-in-another-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
${basedir}
```

property.
This property contains the directory from which the build.xml is invoked.