# Importing ant path-like structures from a build file in another directory

Tags: ant

I have two ANT build files, located in different directories. I would like to `<include>` the contents of a `<path>` element in one from the other.

This seems like it ought to be simple enough to do, but I haven't been able to find documentation on how to do it properly, as ANT insists on always evaluating `<path>` elements relative to the current `basedir` (which is wrong, due to accessing it from a file in another directory).

Answer (score 0):

> This seems like it ought to be simple enough to do, but I haven't been able to find documentation on how to do it properly, as ANT insists on always evaluating  elements relative to the current basedir (which is wrong, due to accessing it from a file in another directory).

ANT is not wrong to do this. A **build.xml** file is normally present at the root of a project's (or project sub-component's) file system and represent's the logic for that build.

If you wish to share a path between two project's, then that is a bad idea, two projects would rarely share exactly the same build path.....

Alternatively, if you are trying to share a path between two project sub-components, why don't you [overide the default value of the basdir](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) property as follows?

```
<project name="my-project" default="build" basedir="..">
..
```

Finally, I would suggest investigating the use of a dependency manager like [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Let it manage your build's classpaths for you.

## Update

Another option is to structure your project's files so that the path dependencies lie in the same relative file system path:

```
$ tree
.
|-- lib
|   |-- dependency1.jar
|   `-- dependency2.jar
|-- sub-component1
|   `-- build.xml
`-- sub-component2
    `-- build.xml
```

Each sub-component **build.xml** then declares it's own path as follows:

```
<path id="build.path">
    <fileset dir="../lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: It is two project sub-components, but wouldn't that solution force everything in both build files to use the same basedir? I don't want that, I just want to use the contents of a single specific `<path>` element, and have it evaluate to what it would in the original file.

Comment: @RyanArcher Alternative option posted

Comment: That's kind of a roundabout solution...isn't there some command to just make path evaluate from a different basedir? You can easily do that with properties...it seems like there should be a way to do with it with `<path>` elements too.

Comment: Not aware of such a task... I personally don't use properties to manage classpaths. Involves two problems, firstly far easier to pick up dependencies from a directory listing, secondly windows and unix paths have different separators. In conclusion, your ultimate solution is to use a dependency management tool such as Apache ivy.